# Draw a radar in python with multiple scale

Tags: python, matplotlib, vedo

I try to generate a complexe radar with VEDO in python. I found a example code from stackoverflow and I want to modify it.

My goal is to generate a radar multiple scale on each axes. Here is the code I have:

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

class Radar(object):

    def __init__(self, fig, titles, labels, rect=None):
        if rect is None:
            rect = [0.05, 0.05, 0.95, 0.95]

        self.n = len(titles)
        self.angles = np.arange(90, 90+360, 360.0/self.n)
        self.angles = [a % 360 for a in self.angles]
        self.axes = [fig.add_axes(rect, projection="polar", label="axes%d" % i)
                         for i in range(self.n)]

        self.ax = self.axes[0]
        self.ax.set_thetagrids(self.angles, labels=titles, fontsize=14)

        for ax in self.axes[0:]:
            ax.patch.set_visible(False)
            ax.grid("off")
            ax.xaxis.set_visible(False)

        index = 0
        for ax, angle, label in zip(self.axes, self.angles, labels):
            ax.set_rgrids(range(1, label.__len__()+1), angle=angle, labels=label)
            ax.spines["polar"].set_visible(True)
            ax.set_ylim(0, label.__len__())
            index+=1


    def plot(self, values, *args, **kw):
        angle = np.deg2rad(np.r_[self.angles, self.angles[0]])
        values = np.r_[values, values[0]]
        self.ax.plot(angle, values, *args, **kw)



fig = pl.figure(figsize=(6, 6))

titles = list("ABCDE")

labels = [
    list("abc"), list("12345"), list("uvwxy"),
    ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"],
    list("jklmn")
]

radar = Radar(fig, titles, labels)
radar.plot([2,2,2,2,2],  "-", lw=2, color="b", alpha=0.4, label="first")
radar.plot([2.3, 2, 3, 3, 2],"-", lw=2, color="r", alpha=0.4, label="second")
radar.plot([3, 4, 3, 4, 2], "-", lw=2, color="g", alpha=0.4, label="third")
radar.ax.legend()

plt.show()
```

And the result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8SbW.png)

The blue line is not following the good scale on each axe. It seems to correspond to my first axe I think.

Comment: nice code.  what do you mean:  "The blue line is not following the good scale on each axe" please ?

Comment: The blue line should follow the data like that [2,2,2,2,2] and there is a circle at every step for every axes. Is it possible to limit the size of the step  as a arc not a cercle?